# Do std::make_shared and std::make_unique have a "nothrow" version?

Tags: c++, new-operator, std, nothrow

For the new operator, we have the `std::nothrow` version:

```
std::unique_ptr<T> p = new(std::nothrow) T();
```

Do we have something like this for the `std::make_shared` or `std::make_unique`?

Answer (score 14):

No, we don't.  Looking through the cppreference pages for [`make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) and [`make_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared), we see that every version uses the default `new` overload.

It is not difficult to implement one, though, something like this:

```
template <class T, class... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique_nothrow(Args&&... args)
    noexcept(noexcept(T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)))
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new (std::nothrow) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

template <class T, class... Args>
std::shared_ptr<T> make_shared_nothrow(Args&&... args)
    noexcept(noexcept(T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)))
{
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(new (std::nothrow) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

(Note that this version of `make_shared_nothrow` does not avoid double allocation as `make_shared` does.)  C++20 added many new overloads for `make_unique`, but they can be implemented in a similar way.  Also, per [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57092289/do-stdmake-shared-and-stdmake-unique-have-a-nothrow-version/57092496#comment100706985_57092496),

> Don't forget to check the pointer before using it, when using this
>   version.
>   — [Superlokkus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3537677)
>   Jul 18 '19 at 10:46

Comment: Don't forget to check the pointer before using it, when using this version.

Comment: "*we see that every version uses the default new overload.*" `allocate_shared` uses the provided allocator, not `new`. Also, if a user wants to use `nothrow` `new`, that probably means they don't want to turn on exception handling period.

Comment: @NicolBolas I absolutely can't imagine how `allocate_shared` got in there ... Thank you!

Comment: @NicolBolas As for exception handling, I wanted to keep consistent with the expression `new (nothrow) T(args...)`.  So I propagate the exceptions thrown by the constructor.

Comment: @L.F.: My point is that `new(std::nothrow)` will work in an exception-less build environment, reporting failure to allocate memory with `nullptr`. your suggestion will not, because the system trying to throw `std::bad_alloc` will *fail*, because exception handling is turned off.

Comment: @NicolBolas You are right.  I have reverted my edit.  Can you think of a way to efficiently implement `make_shared_nothrow` to avoid double allocation?

Comment: @L.F.: Not really. There is no provision in the allocator model for failure to allocate to be signaled by returning null, so `allocate_shared` isn't available.